# PHP Check if option is set, if not fallback to default value

Tags: php, isset

I'm trying to output the option value which the user has saved using a settings form.

I added some checks to it so the option value is never undefined.

`$option[3]` returns the default value of the option. I'm trying to use this when there's no option saved by the user in the database.

`$getoption[$option[0]]` is the user option from the database which the user has saved.

The line below is causing the issue. Some user options return `false`. For some reason, the line below thinks the option is undefined and returns `$option[3]` instead of the saved value, which is `false`.

```
$optionvalue = ( !isset($getoption[$option[0]]) ) ? $option[3] : $getoption[$option[0]];
```

How can I make it so it returns `false` aswell, but if there's nothing saved in the database, have it return `$option[3]`?

---

Sample data:

```
$database_option = false; // <-- by the user
$default_option = true; // <-- only return when there's nothing in $database_option (false is not considered 'nothing')

$optionvalue = ( !isset($database_option) ) ? $default_option : $database_option;

echo $optionvalue; // I want this to return 'false'
```

Comment: do you have any sample data ?

Comment: urg, double negatives and confusing variable names make for horrible code. Drop the ternary and give everything a logical name. That way the code is readable, and you can set some breakpoints and step through the code and see whats broken

Comment: Simply removing the double negative would be a good 1st step: `$optionvalue = isset($getoption[$option[0]]) ?  $getoption[$option[0]] : $option[3];` or in php 7 using null coalescing operator: `$optionvalue = $getoption[$option[0]] ?? $option[3];` however your code works as you intended, so something else is wrong

Answer (score 0):

`isset($variable)` normally returns `true` even if the variable has a value `false`. It return `false` only if the value is `null`. Please refer, http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. 
So, you need to either set the return value for user option as `null` or you can exactly check for `false` like below,

```
//Incorrect Answer
// $optionvalue = ( $getoption[$option[0]] == null || $getoption[$option[0]] == "" ) ? $option[3] : $getoption[$option[0]];

//Updated Answer
$optionvalue = ((isset($getoption[$option[0]]) && $getoption[$option[0]] == '') || !isset($getoption[$option[0]])) ? $option[3] : $getoption[$option[0]];
```

---

**Update:** J.Doe, I have tried variuos options & posted the update below. I hope this helps you.

```
/* These options prints the exact value assigned to the variable as result  */
$db_option = false; //-> Returns False
// $db_option = 5;  //-> Returns 5
// $db_option = 'String';  //-> Returns 'String'
// $db_option = true;  //-> Returns true

/* These options prints 'Default' as result */
// $db_option = ''; //-> Returns 'Default'
// $db_option = null; //-> Returns 'Default'
// unset($db_option); //-> Returns 'Default'
// Also, If there is no variable defined at all //-> Returns 'Default'

/* Default option */
$default_option = true;

$optionvalue = ((!isset($db_option)) || (isset($db_option) && ($db_option === '')) ) ? $default_option : $db_option;
var_dump($optionvalue);
```

Comment: This appears to suggest the ops code is working (they want to read `false` into the variable `$optionvalue` if it is set that way).

Comment: @Steve, I did not understand the question this way. If the value of the user option is false, then he need to return `$option[3]`. J.Doe, can you please clarify our different opinions

Comment: To clarify, I want to return `$option[3]` when there's no value at all in `$getoption[$option[0]]`, but I do want to return `false` as a value which it currently doesn't.

Comment: Good catch @Steve, thanks(+1). I have just updated the answer. J.Doe, can you please check the code if it helps

Comment: @manian Thank you for your effort in helping me out. I've tried your code but it sadly does not seem to work. I'm getting a undefined index error, and the code falls back to the default option `$option[3]`. The value of `$getoption[$option[0]]` is empty when this happens.

Comment: oh ok. as @Dennis posted in his comments, sample data would have helped. I will try to find a solution

Comment: You might need to check for null as well like `$optionvalue = ((isset($getoption[$option[0]]) && ($getoption[$option[0]] == '' || $getoption[$option[0]] == null)) || !isset($getoption[$option[0]])) ? $option[3] : $getoption[$option[0]];`

Comment: @manian It still falls back to the default value. I will probably rethink my code and try to fix it some other way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146763/discussion-between-manian-and-j-doe).

Comment: @J.Doe, I have posted an updated answer here. Please check. I hope it helps you this time.

Answer (score 0):

isset() function only check if the variable is NULL or not. You should check your condition with value.

$optionvalue = ( $getoption[$option[0]] == "" ) ) ? $option[3] : $getoption[$option[0]];